# How to get a percent value

Tags: php

Okay, so for my website, I made a tests system, where you can take quizes. It all works, but getting the percentage of correct answers is broken.

I have 3 variables I am trying to use to get the percentage.

```
$incorrect // Int value of incorrect answers
$correct // Int value of correct answers
$perc // Percentage of correct answers from 0 to 100
```

Currently, I use this, but it does not work:

```
if($incorrect===0){
   $perc = 100;
}elseif($correct===0){
   $perc = 0;
}else{
   $perc = ($incorrect / $correct)*100;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$perc = $correct*100/($incorrect+$correct)
```

Answer (score 0):

User1950001, as Barmar mentioned, you need to calculate the TOTAL number of answers as a percentage is calculated by **`(NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL x 100 / TOTAL`)**.

In this case, CORRECT. is your NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL and `INCORRECT + CORRECT` is your TOTAL, which is what you were missing.

With your original code, `perc = ($incorrect/$correct) * 100` where total questions is 25, 20 are incorrect and 5 are correct would return 400% as the value. Obviously this is way off.